# Change Azure Public IP to Sattic

Tags: networking, azure

I have an existing RM VM with a PIP that is currently dynamic.
The VM is running and the PIP has an IP
If I change the PIP to Static via the portal, will this preserve the current IP address. Or does it get a new IP from a static pool ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The VM is running and the PIP has an IP If I change the PIP to Static
>   via the portal, will this preserve the current IP address. Or does it
>   get a new IP from a static pool ?

I test in my lab. When you change from dynamic to static on Azure Portal, it will preserve the current IP address. The IP address will not change.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do this numerous times (change from a PIP to a static IP).  Every time it changes the IP to a new PIP which then becomes static.